# Is there a way to save and restore a set of tabs in a linux file manager?

Tags: linux, file-management, tabs

For a frequent task, I need a file manager window open with about 8 tabs, each a different location. I'd like to be able to open the tabs once and then save them as a "tab set", so that in future sessions, I can simply open a file manager and restore the saved tab set, without having to open each tab manually.

I'm running Mint 16 with Thunar, but could use a different file manager if needed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Krusader, it looks a little daunting at first if you're used to a windows style manager. It has great tab management, I also use it on Mint, a lot of customization options.

Checking it out is easy as apt-get install krusader

It's build with kde libs, so if you don't have them installed, lookout for the extra weight.

Answer (score 0):

[GNOME Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) (formerly, Nautilus) is another option. It has tabs and, if it doesn't remember tab sessions, it *does* have easy-to-use bookmarks that would make opening all eight tabs a very fast process.

Unsurprisingly, GNOME Files is built against the GTK libraries (which most distributions have preinstalled for one reason or another), so you'll need them installed as dependencies—but, as I mentioned, you may very well already have them.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it would work on **Mint** but you could have a look at [SpaceFM](https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/spacefm/wiki).

More info: https://askubuntu.com/a/872816/142795